# How to reset a variable in a function when a condition happens in the scope?

Tags: c++, variables

I'm using a random number generating function and it's working fine but I need to reset a function variable `nSeed` and let the function startover when an `if` happens in the scope, let's say `nSeed=5323`.

How can i return it to its starting value `5323` when int `a%16==0`? I'm not sure how to do it.

Here's an example:

```
unsigned int PRNG()  

{  
    static unsigned int nSeed = 5323;  
    nSeed = (8253729 * nSeed + 2396403);  
    return nSeed  % 32767;
}  

int main()
{
   int count=0;  
   int a=3;
   int b=5;
   while(count<1000)  
   {  
       count=count+1; 
       a=a+b; 
       cout<<PRNG()<<endl;  

          if(a%16==0)
          {  
               nSeed= 5323;   //here's the problem, "Error nSeed wasn't 
                              //declared in the scoop"
          } 
   }  
}
```

Comment: declare nSeed before the while loop and pass it as a reference to PRNG.

Comment: Put `nSeed` somewhere where you can reach it, for example by making `PRNG` an object of a class and keeping `nSeed` as a member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to learn about scope of a variable. In you case main does not know what is `nSeed`, as it is declared out side of that function. Declare `nSeed` as a global variable as you are referring it in two different functions `main` and `PRNG()`.

Declare like `static unsigned int nSeed = 5323;` just after the header files. Move it out of `PRNG()`

Comment: you're awesome, Simple yet effective .. Thanks mate.

Comment: Global varaibles can seemingly solve alot of problems. But you should be aware of the potential issues for relying on global variables.

Comment: @user3437460, Yes very true. I am just giving him a easy solution as he is a beginner.

Answer (score 3):

One way to make this work could be to place the `PRNG` function inside a class:

```
struct PRNG {
    static unsigned int nSeed;
    unsigned int operator()()
    {
        nSeed = (8253729 * nSeed + 2396403);
        return nSeed % 32767;
    }
};

unsigned int PRNG::nSeed{5323};

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    while(count < 1000)
    {
        count = count + 1;
        a = a + b;
        cout << PRNG()() << endl;

        if(a % 16 == 0)
        {
            PRNG::nSeed = 5323;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't want a static variable:

```
struct PRNG {
    unsigned int nSeed{5323};
    unsigned int operator()()
    {
        nSeed = (8253729 * nSeed + 2396403);
        return nSeed % 32767;
    }
};


int main()
{
    PRNG prng;
    int count = 0;
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    while(count < 1000)
    {
        count = count + 1;
        a = a + b;
        cout << prng() << endl;

        if(a % 16 == 0)
        {
            prng.nSeed = 5323;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, using a lambda:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int nSeed{5323};
    auto prng = [&nSeed](){ 
        return (nSeed = 8253729 * nSeed + 2396403) % 32767; 
    };
    int count = 0;
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    while(count < 1000)
    {
        count = count + 1;
        a = a + b;
        cout << prng() << endl;

        if(a % 16 == 0)
        {
            nSeed = 5323;
        }
    }
}
```